# NGINX Using proxy_set_header Host $host; sends me to 404

Tags: nginx, php

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name _;

    location /test/ {
    proxy_pass http://example.com/page.php;
    }
}
```

Currently when I use this Nginx reverse proxy, when I visit from `test.com/test/`, it serves me `https://example.com/page.php` but the url stays the same. When I call `$_SERVER['http_host']`, it returns the hostname of example.com instead of the hostname I made the request from (url in the domain).

I tried using: `proxy_set_header Host $host;` however that leads me to a 404 page after I run that.

In short,

I would like to visit `test.com/test` and be served http://example.com/page.php`but have the`hostname`of`test.com/test`when I call`$_SERVER` in PHP

EDIT:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen  80;
        server_name _;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host; #works without this
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_intercept_errors on;

        proxy_pass http://example.com;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `proxy_set_header` is how you're supposed to do it.  There's some crucial point to this you're not telling us.  Helpfully, once you figure out what that is, you'll almost certainly have the answer to your question.

Comment: @womble it's really weird because once I remove `proxy_set_header Host`, it'll work as intended. I've included the full config file.

Comment: What do the nginx debug logs say?  I'm guessing it's not nginx that's deciding to emit the 404.

Comment: I'm using an AWS EC2 instance to run this, however you're right the 404 belongs to godaddy. I'll take a look at the logs!

Comment: Looks like the error log is empty when I just tried to check it.